# .htaccess check for cookie first, then valid-user

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess

I have a .htaccess file for a directory on my apache server. Currently this makes use of mod_auth_mysql for user verification to view the directory listing. However, if the user is already logged in to my application (therefore a cookie exists), I want to skip the valid user requirement and therefore eliminate multiple logins.

**Current .htaccess**

```
AuthName "Please don't hack the server, cheers"
AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
AuthUserFile /dev/null
AuthMySQL On
AuthType Basic
Auth_MYSQL on
Auth_MySQL_Host localhost
Auth_MySQL_User username
Auth_MySQL_Password password
AuthMySQL_DB auth
AuthMySQL_Password_Table users
Auth_MySQL_Username_Field username
Auth_MySQL_Password_Field password
Auth_MySQL_Empty_Passwords Off
Auth_MySQL_Encryption_Types Plaintext
Auth_MySQL_Authoritative On
require user james
```

**The Cookie Check**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^cookiename=ok$
RewriteRule .* / [NC,L]
```

How do I combine these two correctly, to first check for the cookie and allow through if found, and then check for a valid user if the cookie is not found?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do 2 things here, you can create an environment variable using the [`SetEnvIf` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) and check it against `Cookie`. Then you need to tell mod_auth_mysql to allow *any* set of requirements to satisfy the authentication.

First the environment variable:

```
SetEnvIf Cookie cookiename=ok norequire_auth=yes
```

The `cookiename=ok` is a regular expression that matches against the **Cookie:** HTTP header. Then the `Satisfy`:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Satisfy Any

# your auth stuff:
AuthName "Please don't hack the server, cheers"
AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
AuthUserFile /dev/null
AuthMySQL On
AuthType Basic
Auth_MYSQL on
Auth_MySQL_Host localhost
Auth_MySQL_User username
Auth_MySQL_Password password
AuthMySQL_DB auth
AuthMySQL_Password_Table users
Auth_MySQL_Username_Field username
Auth_MySQL_Password_Field password
Auth_MySQL_Empty_Passwords Off
Auth_MySQL_Encryption_Types Plaintext
Auth_MySQL_Authoritative On
require user james

Allow from env=norequire_auth
```

So the `Satisfy Any` means we allow if `require user james` is satisfied **or** if `Allow from env=norequire_auth` is satisfied. Without the satisfy, both lines would need to be satisfied in order to allow access.

Note that cookies can easily be forged and this system isn't a good way to protect your pages. You'd at least need to check the cookie's value for a session ID or something.

Comment: Thanks for this - however, after adding the SetEvnIf to the top of the .htaccess and the "Satisfy All" next, it seems to let anyone through without requiring any authentication. Any chance something in the httpd.conf could override this that I need to look at?

Comment: @Jimbo Is there another "Allow from" somewhere?

Comment: Nope, there was a `deny from all` missing - I edited, I hope that's okay. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Hey @Jon Lin , being an expert on this sort of stuff you might be interested in seeing my followup question as to why this has stopped working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396655/httpd-conf-code-not-working-correctly-suggestions - easy points? :)